# Installing Nvidia driver 340 on Ubuntu 14.04

Tags: 14.04, drivers, nvidia

I am trying to install the proprietary Nvidia drivers on Ubuntu 14.04, which has a GeForce 880M graphics card (laptop). From the NVidia website, it tells me that I need the driver version 340. Here is what I have done so far:

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:xorg-edgers/ppa
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install nvidia-340
```

After this, in Ubuntu Software Centre -> Software Sources -> Additional Drivers, I chose to select the 340 driver. Then I rebooted my machine.

After rebooting, the screen seems to freeze every couple of minutes or so. There is no response from the mouse or keyboard. The only way to regain responsiveness is by entering tty (Ctrl Alt F1) and then returning to the desktop (Ctrl Alt F7). However, a few minutes later, the screen freezes again.

I have now reinstalled a fresh copy of Ubuntu, updated the Nvidia drivers as the first thing after installation, and the same thing is happening. Any ideas on how I can address this?